# How to set current document.domain in WebBrowser Control to avoid "Access is denied"?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, cross-domain, access-denied

How can I set current `document.domain` in WebBrowser Control to avoid "Access is denied" in Cross-domain calls (XMLHTTP Requests or Iframe/frame access)?

I've tried

```
CurrentDocument = WebBrowserControl.Document
CurrentDocument.domain = "example.com"
Console.writeline("xx" & CurrentDocument.domain)
```

This doesn't work, somehow it never reaches console.writeline

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I use `WebBrowserControl.ActiveXInstance` ?

Comment: I need this very same thing. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @jsoldi No      ... . . . ..     .

Answer (score 1):

What language are you writing this in? Are you accessing the property [.Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.domain.aspx) or the non-existant property .domain?

Comment: This is VB.NET I'm trying accessing document.domain property. It's OK to read but I can't overwrite it.

Comment: Hmm - I'm testing your code in a simple VB.net application, and I get an ArgumentException thrown on the second line. Are you also getting an exception?

(Also, if I use CurrentDocument.domain, VS2008 corrects it to CurrentDocument.Domain. I can't find any reference to a lowercase .domain property.)

Comment: Stobor thanks for answer (it's VB.NET so not case-sensitive, sry for the example). Now I isolate the project and also I'm getting ArgumenException. Basically it doesn't accept anything but the correct domain, so I'm stuck!