# How to carry out Cross Domain request in a Webbrowser Control?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest

As you know doing Cross Domain XMLHTTP requests is not allowed for security reasons under Internet Explorer.

I have a WebBrowser Control and I'm using `DocumentText` instead of `Navigate` to a URL. Since the current domain is `about:blank` when the page tries to do a request to itself or other domain I'm getting `Access is denied` Javascript error.

Even when I use `Navigate` if the Javascript do a request to another domain it doesn't work.

How can I get around this?

This HTML code should work with WebBrowser Control:

```
<body>

<a href="javascript:getit('http://www.google.com')">this should work</a>
<div id="x"></div>

</body>

<script>
function XHConn()
{
  var xmlhttp, bComplete = false;
  try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
  catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
  catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
  catch (e) { xmlhttp = false; }}}
  if (!xmlhttp) return null;
  this.connect = function(sURL, sMethod, sVars, fnDone)
  {
    if (!xmlhttp) return false;
    bComplete = false;
    sMethod = sMethod.toUpperCase();

    try {
      if (sMethod == "GET")
      {
        xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL+"?"+sVars, true);
        sVars = "";
      }
      else
      {
        xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST "+sURL+" HTTP/1.1");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && !bComplete)
        {
          bComplete = true;
          fnDone(xmlhttp);
        }};
      xmlhttp.send(sVars);
    }
    catch(z) { return false; }
    return true;
  };
  return this;
}

function getit(url){
    var xmlhttp = new XHConn();
    var fnWhenDone = function (oXML) { document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = oXML.responseText; alert(oXML.responseText); };
    xmlhttp.connect(url, "GET", "", fnWhenDone);
}

</script>
```

- **I don't have control over Javascript / HTML code, my application only hosts a Webbrowser Control**
- *I found something called [CROSS_DOMAIN_DATA URL Action Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537178(VS.85).aspx), not sure if it's right direction. Even it's I'm not sure how to implement it.*
- Also if you can answer to this question : [How to set current document.domain in WebBrowser Control to avoid “Access is denied”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411626/how-to-set-current-document-domain-in-webbrowser-control-to-avoid-access-is-denie) that's  enough for me as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a dirty workaround, load a local HTML (c:\temp\temp.html) and then modify the content of it via javascript.

After this point there is no more CrossDomain restrictions however using document.write causing other nasty problems such as JQuery `.ready` functions won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, it worked for me like a charm.
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;246227

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand on which domain you don't have access to the Javascript...
Have you tried using the **script** tag to get the data that you want from a different domain? You can use the [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) idiom to namespace the data...

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "anotherdomain.com/data?callback=myFunction";
head.appendChild(script);
```

And then on "/data":

```
myFunction({
    // data here
});
```

Comment: I don't have the control over Javascript code. So I can't change it. But I want to allow Webbrowser Control to do Cross-domain requests without a specific library such as JSONP. Also it's fine if I can just change the current document.domain. But that doesn't look possible either without navigate.

Comment: You're going to need JSONP, I think.

Comment: How can this NOT be Javascript relevant if you're talking about Internet Explorer Security issues using XMLHTTP? Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Webbrowser Control stuff.

Answer (score 0):

URLACTION-CROSS-DOMAIN-DATA seems to be the right direction:
[Read this to find out why](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: any idea how to implement in .NET ? :)

Comment: I will leave that you as an exercise. But here is a failed attempt which might help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/536927fb-edbd-4004-ace2-58c592184b60/ :) gl&hf :D

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to make sure your code runs in the trusted zone (or higer like HTA). By default, anything running inside the WebBrowser control runs in the zone that the files which are being served come from. (i.e. the standard IE security policies are being used.)

To change this behaviour, you'll need to change the application which is hosting the WebBrowser control and implement a few interfaces on that WebBrowser control. (IInternetHostSecurityManager,  IInternetZoneManager and IInternetSecurityMgrSite are the ones that you should take a look at.) This is not a trivial task and the documentation about this is scarce at best.

Once this is done, your code can run with any privileges you need, and cross-domain requests are just as easy as resetting Mime-Sweeper high scores.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, definitely this is way to go. The problem though is the implementation. I've tried so many things and actually tried to implements zones as well as URL_POLICY_ALLOW stuff. Even though they work for some other stuff they didn't work for CROSS DOMAIN communication.

Comment: Have you tried to do cross domain requests using a HTA? An HTA is a HTML application that has full privileges. If it works in an HTA, it will work with this technique. Implementing it though is a different story...