# WebBrowser not support cross domain?

Tags: c#

i have a problem with [C#]WebBrowser.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiCAd.png

My app navigation to file index.html.
This is content of file index.html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url:'http://192.168.0.3:8000/device/ping',
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

It only working width chrome,IE...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CpIn.png

But it not working in WebBrowser

Please help me :)
Thank all.

Comment: When you say "WebBrowser", are you referring to the Winform control?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415926/how-to-carry-out-cross-domain-request-in-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: The webbrowser control using the IE as its rendering engine. there are some options you may need to set for the web browser control to interpret the javascripting side of things correctly. you may need to set the IsScriptEnabled  property to true

Comment: This could help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/how-do-i-display-a-popup-from-a-webbrowser-in-another-window-i-created] you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible because of security reasons.

Comment: Yep, I have tried and but it not working,
I create a new javascript function in ObjectForScripting. to do it